# IS there a better extension method than FindIndex to filter on a generic list?

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I'm trying to execute method "UpdateConnection" against a qualified element in a list. I didn't see "Where" or "Select" as avaliable extension methods. Is there a cleaner way to filter on this list other than "FindIndex"?

```
public class ExistingDbConnection
{
    public string DBName { get; set; }
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
}

var list = new List<ExistingDbConnection>();

ExistingDbConnection p = new ExistingDbConnection() { DBName = "MS100", ID = Guid.NewGuid() };
list.Add(p);
p = new ExistingDbConnection() { DBName = "DS100", ID = Guid.NewGuid() };
list.Add(p);


var index = exisingConnections.FindIndex(x => x.DBName == connection.Name);
if (index < 0) index = 0;  // if no match, use the first element
status = await UpdateConnection(exisingConnections[index].Id);
```

Comment: `using System.Linq;` ?

Comment: System.Linq was missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use `FirstOrDefault` extension method which might let your code clear from `System.Linq` namespace.

```
var item = exisingConnections.FirstOrDefault(x=> x.DBName == connection.Name) ?? exisingConnections[0];
status = await UpdateConnection(item.Id);
```